# In-Project-Videos - Where to store them and which format?

Tags: android, video

I have a quite complex android app and for several functions
i want to provide some tutorial videos inside the application.

- Where do i have to put my Video-Files in my project? Also in the
  drawable folder like my images?
- Which format? (mpg, av, ...)
- Do i also have to provide different qualities like mdpi, hdpi, ...?

I want to provide a ListView with a thumbnail of the video, a title and 
a small description. after the user clicks on an item of the listview
i want the selected video to be played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will have lots of videos, you probably don't want to put it inside apk, because apk size is limited + not every user wants to download and store on device app which is more than 50 mb. I recommend you to upload your videos to youtube ( just create you channel and upload as more videos as you need). Than you will be able to use [youtube android api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) to show your videos inside app.

If you don't have lots of videos (overall < 50 mb), I recommend you to create folder `row` inside `res` folder and store all your videos there. Then you will be able to access it with built in [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html). It supports  next formats: [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Example of usage VideoView:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.filename));
videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a folder 'raw' to your res folder and store videos in them .
And for formats see : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

And see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348850/4465685